# Expression Encoder Free version vs Pro version

Tags: c#, video-encoding, expression-encoder-sdk, expression-encoder-4

I am evaluating a media encode/playback technology for my media project[I need to do stuff like clipping/trimming/joining video, screen capture, add overlays etc], its a WPF/C# based project. I have gone through Expression Encoder/Media Foundation.NET/DirectShow.Net and found out that Expression Encoder seems to have a clear and easy to use API. I am confused about the capabilities that the free version offers, I could not found any article which could clearly differentiate what is available in free version and what is not. Also is Expression Encoder Pro 4 even available for sale now, if so how much does it cost, do they allow access to full API for development purpose?

Can somebody who has worked on these technologies suggest which technology will be suitable for my project and whats the difference in the two Encoder versions in terms of capibilities? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As it is stated at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression - Expression Encoder 4 Pro is no longer available for purchase. Expression Encoder 4 remains available for download at no charge. There are too many limitations in free version (the most significant one is lack of support for H.264), so I wouldn't recommend you to use it. You'd better check ffmpeg and other solutions.

Comment: Umirov: Thanks for your response, Can you suggest any SDK which replaced EE4 or any other alternative?

Comment: There is no replacement for EE4 from Microsoft, which is sad, since it is the only product that was creating videos for smooth streaming. As I understood, MS wanted everybody to switch to their Azure-hosted Media Services - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/ You can search for projects like mencoder, ffmpeg, etc. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914078/ffmpeg-vs-mencoder